# Xamarin.Forms: editing (in VS) custom control's property value at runtime in XAML doesn't cause any updates

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom control in Xamarin.Forms app that's described via XAML. For example, *CustomControl.xaml*:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             x:Class="Sample.CustomControl">
    <Ellipse Fill="White"
             WidthRequest="32"
             HeightRequest="32">
    </Ellipse>
</ContentView>
```

And corresponding *CustomControl.xaml.cs*:

```
public partial class CustomControl: ContentView
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

If I use this control in my *MainPage.xaml* and set some of its' properties, they are applied correct at startup, but then if I try to change any of values at runtime, nothing happens.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Sample;assembly=Sample"
             x:Class="Sample.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <controls:CustomControl x:Name="CustomControl"
                                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5" // <- At startup this control is positioned in center but then if I change this property at runtime layout doesn't rearrange
                                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
            </controls:CustomControl>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

At the same time, if I move those properties from *MainPage.xaml* to the root level of *CustomControl.xaml.cs* and change them at runtime, layout rearranges like expected:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             x:Class="Sample.CustomControl"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5" // <- If I place this property in child's XAML and change it at runtime the position of element changes
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
    <Ellipse Fill="White"
             WidthRequest="32"
             HeightRequest="32">
    </Ellipse>
</ContentView>
```

Maybe this thing is related to XAML hot reload, because binding of that property works in both cases, no matter where I set property binding (at 'control' level or at 'page' level). Could someone explain, why changing property value in page XAML file at runtime doesn't cause any updates?

---

**UPDATE 24.04.2022**

I found the solution. I had to change 'Hot Reload mode' to 'Full page' in VS settings. Now during debug session every change that I make to XAML files is reflected immediately.
[image]

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Well, I made those changes not by code, but by editing XAML files of my controls during debug. Usually those changes are applied immediately because of XAML Hot Reload, but I faced a problem which I described in my question. Anyway, I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do you set the property value at runtime. I had done a simple and test your code. If I put the following code into a button's clicked event in the page.cs, the position of element will change when the button is clicked.

```
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(CustomControl,
new Rectangle(0.6f,
    0.8f, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));
```

If you need more information, please check the api about the AbsoluteLayout:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.absolutelayout?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question was about seeing changes made to XAML files of my components during debug, it didn't work as I expected, but I found a solution.